# when i type letter like m i get number like 0 value in laptop how to fix

Tags: keyboard

My dads laptop has a problem. The keys on the keyboard that have a second symol on the key example the letter m has a 0. The letter L has a 3 and so on. 
It seems that some how it is set as default to write the secondary symbol. Any body know how to set as it was before.

Comment: ask a question, self answering the same minute? I do not see many ppl having the same problem - and if - it is a hardware problem, not programming related so its OT for SO.

Comment: i think this forms is for helping people i counter problem then i found solution for help others i share it here, this is not hadware problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i see there are many people having this trouble
please note that many laptops not have num keys so the letter keys are worked for both alphabet as well as numeric key many people turn on these numeric keys without knowing.
So you just need to turn off numlock in many laptops numlock key not work lonely it will work with combination like fn+numlock i will give most common below:

```
Fn + F11 (Acer, Toshiba, Samsung)  
Shift + Num Lock  
Fn + Num Lock (Sony, Gateway)  
Fn + F11 + Scroll lock  
Fn + F8 (HP)  
Ctrl + F11  
Fn + Shift + Num Lock  
Fn + F4 (Dell)  
Fn + Nmlk (Lenovo, ASUS)
```

hope it will help you